# Downsizing Volume for a DB instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently using gp2 volumes on AWS to store data. In an effort to improve baseline performance, I increased the volume size by 50 times. However, I am now planning to migrate to gp3 volumes, which are known to provide good performance even at lower volume sizes.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to downsize the volume on AWS, which is preventing me from optimizing my storage solution. What are the ways I can do the downsizing?

Answer (score 3):

You can only increase the size of an EBS volume. You cannot decrease it.

If you want to have a smaller volume, you need to create a new one, and migrate your data to it.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ebs-increase-decrease-volume-size

Comment: I want to add one more thing, I have around 35 AWS accounts and have 3 DB instances going through the path you suggested would be a hectic task. Is there any other way I can achieve downsizing?